# request focus on edit text

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have got different issue in android application. I have taken 3 EditTexts in order. My intention is when I setOnClick on 1st editText the virtual keypad appearing. When i clicked on next on virtual key pad the courser is displaying in 2nd EditText. But i should not get the courser in 2nd editText it shoulod focus on 3rd EditText. How can I focus in 3rd edittext?

Please, help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify

> android:nextFocusDown

property in your layout.xml. For example (for edittext1):

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext3"
```

Comment: You are wellcome. Please, follow Vladimir Ivanov's advice and mark some of your answers as correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Call [`requestFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) on your third editText.